# How can I load csv file into neo4j if I want the value of key to be in a list format instead of string?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

If I want to import artist.csv with following data into Neo4j database. How can I load album (last index). I could only load into neo4j if last index was inside the quotes "".

```
1,ABBA,['WATER LOO', 'ARRIVAL']
2,BEATLES, [LET IT BE]
```

I tried

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///artist.csv' AS line
 CREATE (:Artist { name: line[1], album: line[2]})
```

Result I was looking for is

```
{
  "name": "ABBA",
  "album": ["WATER LOO, ARRIVAL"]
}
{
  "name": "BEATLES",
  "album": [" LET IT BE"]
}
```

Result I am getting is :

```
{
  "name": "ABBA",
  "album": "['WATER LOO', 'ARRIVAL']"
}
{
  "name": "BEATLES",
  "album": " LET IT BE"
}
```

If I were to have a csv  with albums in different column, can I combine those while loading in neo4j?

```
id,artist,album_1, album_2
1,ABBA,WATER LOO, ARRIVAL
2,BEATLES, LET IT BE,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LOAD CSV` clause uses the comma character as the default delimiter between columns, so extraneous commas will be treated as column delimiters as well. You should use a different delimiter for your album array (e.g., ';'). Also, that clause already treats all file data as strings, so you do not want to surround a string with quote characters unless you actually want to include the quotes as part of the string value.

Here is one solution:

1. Change your data file to this format:

   ```
   1,ABBA,WATER LOO;ARRIVAL
   2,BEATLES,LET IT BE
   ```
2. Use this query:

   ```
   LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///artist.csv' AS line
   CREATE (a:Artist {name: line[1], albums: SPLIT(line[2], ';')})
   RETURN a
   ```

   The result will be:

   ```
   ╒════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
   │"a"                                             │
   ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
   │{"name":"ABBA","albums":["WATER LOO","ARRIVAL"]}│
   ├────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
   │{"name":"BEATLES","albums":["LET IT BE"]}       │
   └────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
   ```

Comment: Thank you Cybersam